# Possible bug with Dataset formatting for incompatible shapes and Missing

Tags: bugs, front-end, formatting, dataset

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and fixed in 11.1**

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3707497] was created.
>
> [...] It does appear that `Dataset` typesetting in version 11 is not behaving properly, and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. [...]

---

The problem:

```
{<|"a" -> Range[5]|>, <|"a" -> Missing["KeyAbsent", "a"]|>} // Dataset
```

> [image]

More detailed example shows that `5` is the magic number and that it will be quite common for those who use `KeyUnion`:

```
 Table[<|ToString[i] -> Range[i]|>, {i, 2, 6}] // KeyUnion // Dataset
```

> [image]

---

Keywords:

`` TypeSystem`PackageScope`AtomShape[34] ``

---

Comment: It worked in Version 10.4.1, but does not in Version 11.0.0.

Comment: I note, that `Missing["reason"]` does not work in general (e.g. the *reason* is not printed anymore when the `Dataset`is displayed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove it from unanswered stack:

> The bug was fixed in V11.1